# Presto cassandra connector issue

Tags: cassandra, connector, presto

I am trying to connect to presto for cassandra as below
./presto --server localhost:7070 --catalog cassandra
when i try to execute any query on it, it shows following error:
Error running command: Server refused connection: http://localhost:7070/v1/statement
i am new to it and have tried every possible effort to solve this.
could someone help me in this?

Comment: What port do you have Presto running on? You can see that via `http-server.http.port=8080` in config.properties (see https://prestodb.io/docs/current/installation/deployment.html for more info on deploying Presto)

Comment: Actually 8080 is being used for tomcat. i have assigned it to run on 7070 in the config file.

Comment: i have seen one more issue. prest0 0.147, 0.162 run with presto client 0.167 and 0.177 but presto 0.177 doesn't run with the same client. i want to use recent pretso version with cassandra3.x.